# Direved and integral problème [SCILAB]

Tags: scilab, integral, derived

I'm working on a project that calculates the derivative of the speed and the integral of the acceleration.
my problem is that I have a lot of acceleration points and speed over time and I can not find the right program for that.

example:

- acceleration from 0 km / h to 40 km / h in 5 seconds
- from 5 to 10 seconds, the speed is constant 40km/h;
- from 10 to 17 seconds there is a deceleration from 40 km / h to 20 km / h

So dv/dt = (v2-v1)/(t2-t1) but I don't know how to declare multiple variables for v1 v2 t1 t2

```
function a=acc(v1,v2,t1,t2)
     a= (v2-v1)/(t2-t1)
endfunction
v1=
v2=
t1=
t2=
disp(acc(v1,v2,t1,t2),'acc = ')
```

and the same for the integral of (dv/dt)*dt

please help me guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
V(1:5) = linspace(0,40,5);
V(6:10) = 40;
V(11:17) = linspace(40,20,7);

Acc = diff(V);
```

First we populate a array `V` with your values for the speed.

Then we create an array `Acc` with the acceleration a each seconds with `diff`since there's only 1s between two values of V.

Another solution based on what you wrote

```
function a=acc_2(v1,v2,t1,t2)
  a= (v2-v1)./(t2-t1) // since v,t are vectors, we need './' and not '/' !
endfunction
V(1:5) = linspace(0,40,5);
V(6:10) = 40;
V(11:17) = linspace(40,20,7);

v1 = V(1:$-1); 
v2 = V(2:$);
t1 = 1:length(V)-1;
t2 = 2:length(V);
Acc_2 = acc_2(v1,v2,t1,t2)
```

And if you want to have `h(x) = int_t0^x dv/dt dt` then use `cumsum`

`H = cumsum(Acc)`

Comment: i put this 

`V(1:5) = linspace(0,40,5);
V(6:10) = 40;
V(11:17) = linspace(40,20,7);

function a = acc(V)
    a=diff(V)
endfunction


function aa = acc_2(v1,v2,t1,t2)
    aa = (v2-v1)/(t2-t1)
endfunction
v1 = V(1:$-1); 
v2 = V(2:$);
t1 = 1:length(V)-1;
t2 = 2:length(V);
Acc_2 = acc_2(v1,v2,t1,t2)`


but he gives me the result of a single variable of Acc_2 ?

Comment: Use the dot division `./` an  not the slash `/` operator. so acc_2 is `(v2-v1)./(t2-t1)`

Comment: thank you very much for your help, just one last question, 


I did not understand the following two codes: 

`v1 = V(1:$-1); 
v2 = V(2:$);`

what is the utility of $ ?

Comment: In scilab, $ refers to the last element of  a vector. And $-i refers to the ith element before it.

Comment: Please, for cumsum,  i want to calculate the integral of (dv / dt) * dt, i tried cumsum but he gave me negative results, and we know that the speed must be positive. any solution ?

Comment: cumsum didnt return negative values for me

Answer (score 0):

i put this code

```
V(1:5) = linspace(0,40,5); 
V(6:10) = 40; 
V(11:17) = linspace(40,20,7); 
function a = acc(V) 
      a=diff(V) 
endfunction 

function aa = acc_2(v1,v2,t1,t2) 
      aa = (v2-v1)/(t2-t1) 
endfunction 

v1 = V(1:$-1); 
v2 = V(2:$); 
t1 = 1:length(V)-1; 
t2 = 2:length(V); 
Acc_2 = acc_2(v1,v2,t1,t2)
```

but he gives me the result of a single variable of Acc_2 ?